# USB storage can't detected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, linux-device-driver

I have a usb mass storage,  and today I insert into usb port, the usb can't be open, I using  "dmesg" to see infomation

```
adan@adan-Latitude-D630:~$ dmesg | tail
[  409.001220] composite sync not supported
[  616.340074] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  617.392967] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3000
[  617.392979] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  617.392987] usb 2-1: Product: SM3255AA MEMORY BAR 
[  617.392994] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[  617.393558] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  618.393265] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access              USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  618.397967] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  618.399479] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

On windows, the usb mass storage was be  detected as USB disk drive,  can't open usb in file browser too.
what's wrong with my usb? how to fix it? thank  you.

Comment: Perhaps, this question better fits http://superuser.com or even http://askubuntu.com . The drive itself is Ok, perhaps, something wrong with the filesystem on it (you didn't provide appropriate logs to judge)

Comment: do you know what extra log should be provided?

Comment: Usually, there should be a message telling that the partition table of the drive has been successfully read and understood: `Apr 20 20:43:01 galene kernel: [18125.559682]  sdb: sdb1`. Take a look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/how-to-salvage-an-unreadable-usb-flash-drive) it seems that those folks have a problem similar to yours